# Apache 2 Administration Tools on Ubuntu or Windows

Tags: apache, apache2, system-administration, admin

I am totally new to Apache and Ubuntu, is there an admin tools where the available functions and features and settings are more accessible? I am finding it very difficult to do even the simplest things.... please help.

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

apacheConf is available for most flavours of Linux, however:

1) it ignores the distribution-specific layout of the config files and implements its own structure

2) its just a tool for updating the config - it doesn't actually tell you what the config options mean

3) like any gui tool it abstracts the actual data (in this case, the apache config) you are manipulating

4) there are at least 3 different programs branded as apacheConf

http://www.apache-gui.com/apache-linux.html

http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/linux/RHL-7.2-Manual/custom-guide/apacheconf.html

and the config tool bundled in Mandriva

5) it limits what you can actually configure to the design on the UI (e.g. RedHat apacheConf only allows you to set one listening address

Having buttons to click does not help you understand what you are actually trying to achieve (unless your objective is an MCSE of course ;). I'd recommend you go get a good book on Apache config and take the time to read it.

C.

Answer (score 4):

Try Webmin - a nice web-based GUI tool.  There is a .deb package for ubuntu in their downloads page.

http://webmin.com

Answer (score 3):

Here are some options to consider for helping you to better understand how Apache works and how to administer/configure the server:

1. Read [the official HOW-TO](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/)
2. Take a look at a commercial tool like [ApacheConf](http://www.apache-gui.com/apache-linux.html)
3. Ask questions here about the specific issues you are having

HTH,

-aj